# __construct() argument error when overriding 2 custom modules from same core module

Tags: magento2, controllers, fatal-error

I get the `__construct()` argument error while trying to override 2 custom modules from same core class as:

**In etc/di - Module1**

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index" />
```

**in Controller class**

```
class Index extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $catalogSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        QueryFactory $queryFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$storeManager,$resultPageFactory,$queryFactory,$layerResolver);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
```

**in etc/di--module2**

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module2\Controller\Result\Index" />
```

**in controller module2**

```
class Index extends \Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $catalogSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Http $request,
        LayoutInterface $layout,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $catalogCategoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Vendor\Module1\Model\Client\Connector $tglssearchClientConnector,
        QueryFactory $queryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$storeManager,$queryFactory,$layerResolver);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->catalogCategoryFactory = $catalogCategoryFactory;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->tglssearchClientConnector = $tglssearchClientConnector;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

        /* parent::__construct(
            $context
        ); */
    }
```

I get:

> Argument 4 passed to
>   Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory, instance of
>   Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_5test\app\code\Vendor\Module2\Controller\Result\Index.php
>   on line 36 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_5test\app\code\Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index.php
>   on line 22

Comment: Try to clean the `var/generation` folder

Comment: its cleared...var/gen and var/cache

Answer (score 2):

In controller module2 try to change:

```
parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$storeManager,$queryFactory,$layerResolver);
```

to the:

```
parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$storeManager,$resultPageFactory,$layerResolver,$queryFactory);
```

because you module1 controller constructor get this params in this order:

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $catalogSession,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    Resolver $layerResolver,
    QueryFactory $queryFactory
) { ... }
```

#### Update:

In module 1 controller class change the line:

```
parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$storeManager,$resultPageFactory,$queryFactory,$layerResolver);
```

to the:

```
parent::__construct($context, $catalogSession, $storeManager, $queryFactory, $layerResolver);
```

**Note:**
clean the `var/generation` folder to see the changes.

Comment: After changing, Argument 4 passed to Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_5test\app\code\Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index.php on line 26 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_5test\app\code\Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index.php on line 53

Comment: @SachinS I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

make the constructor of your first controller class look like this:

```
class Index extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index
{
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $catalogSession,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    Resolver $layerResolver,
    QueryFactory $queryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$storeManager,$queryFactory,$layerResolver);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}
```

and remove the constructor from the second class you posted.

Comment: 1st constructor as said, and 2nd i kept public function __construct(Http $request) {$this->request = $request;} ...Call to a member function dispatch() on null...cleared gen and cache

Comment: Ok thanks guys, fixed it...Class order was the problem..